# How to make a cloned OS drive bootable?

Tags: windows-7, mbr, gpt, efi, bootrepair

I had the misfortune to use EaseUs to clone the OS drive from MBR to GPT using the clone option, not by using the clone system option. The old drive (RAID-0) still works as system drive for Windows 7, but the new drive does not. It gives an MBR error on booting. Hitting F8 has no effect.

Is there a tool or command that works like `bootrec` that can be used on some disk when I've booted from another disk? That is, the new drive shows up when I boot from the old drive. I figure that only the EFI records need to be fixed. Or are there steps of fixing this by using system repair from the working disk?

I can of course do the cloning again, but it took 6hrs so I prefer not to.

Comment: If your getting a MBR error your create a GPT clone

Comment: @ramhound, indeed. The clone is from MBR to GPT. But windows can boot off of a GPT disk, the question is how to fix it.